# Corrections from violation of P-symmetry for chemistry, biochemistry, life?

Tags: symmetry, biophysics, weak-interaction, parity, quantum-chemistry

Imagine a mirror image of a biological cell: all molecules replaced with their symmetric versions ([enantiomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enantiomer)). At least in theory, we should be able to synthesize it ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_life_concept)), for example for mass production of enantiomers of standard biomolecules. It involves also huge dangers (["Mirror-image cells could transform science - or kill us all", WIRED 2010](https://www.wired.com/2010/11/ff_mirrorlife/)).

This race has already started: e.g. in 2016 a mirror version of [polymerase](http://www.nature.com/news/mirror-image-enzyme-copies-looking-glass-dna-1.19918) has been synthesized in Beijing ([Nature News article](http://www.nature.com/news/mirror-image-enzyme-copies-looking-glass-dna-1.19918)).

However, physicists know that **[P-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics))** is not completely conserved, **is violated by weak interaction** - what might lead to some **tiny corrections for chemistry** (?)

**Would violation of P-symmetry have a non-negligible effect on chemistry, biochemistry, life?** How large such corrections would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If P-symmetry is not violated, different enantiomers ($R$ and $S$) of molecules would have the same energy, and the standard reaction enthalpy of interconversion is zero.

$$R \rightleftharpoons S, \quad  \Delta H_r^{\ominus} = 0 $$

However, if parity symmetry is violated, one enantiomer may be favored

$$ R \rightleftharpoons S, \quad \Delta H_r^{\ominus} = \Delta E_{pv}\cdot N_A $$

Where $\Delta E_{pv}$ is the parity-violating energy difference between enantiomers and $N_A$ is Avogadro's number. According to Quack$^{1,2}$ $\Delta E_{pv}$ is on the order of ~$10^{-11}$ J/mol (or ~$10^{-16}$ eV) for a molecule like  CHFClBr. Note these are theoretical values; perhaps someone more up-to-date with the literature will know if any experiments have been successful.

Regardless, it is expected to be extremely small corresponding to an equilibrium constant of essentially 1. However, the slight difference in equilibrium may have been important in the origin of molecular species. The slight shift in equilibrium may have tipped in favor of one enantiomer over another, suggesting a reason as to why life as we know it predominantly, if not exclusively, uses L-amino acids and D-sugars.

1) Quack, Martin. Fundamental symmetries and symmetry violations from high resolution spectroscopy. John Wiley & Sons, Ltd, 2011.

2) Quack, Martin, and Jürgen Stohner. "Influence of parity violating weak nuclear potentials on vibrational and rotational frequencies in chiral molecules." Physical review letters 84.17 (2000): 3807.

Comment: Great thanks for the reply and literature! While I was not afraid of tiny difference in enantiomer statistics, this violation might e.g. lead to differences in protein folding and resulting details of mirror biological macrostructures (e.g. ribosome, cytoskeleton) , but $10^{-16} eV$ difference seems completely negligible. Regarding symmetry breaking in the beginning of our life, a natural explanation is just statistical symmetry breaking: the more one type of life, the more building material its further generations have - statistically leading to complete domination.